# Calling functions within other functions?

Tags: python

I'm really stuck with this, I need to call a function within another function changing the argument while inside but it keeps me saying 'float' object is not callable.

for example:

```
def functioncall(f,epsilon):
   guess = 1.0
   for i in range(100):
      if f(guess) - guess < epsilon:
        return guess
      else:
        guess = f(guess)
```

gives me

```
File "C:/Users/Apoo/Dropbox/6.00x/midTermQuiz1/problem8.py", line 16, in functioncall
    if f(guess) - guess < epsilon:
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I understood that doing so I'm calling the value of the function f, which is a float in my case, but how can I change that?

Comment: What is `f`? Are you sure you didn't switch the order of the arguments?

Comment: f is a function with a single argument that returns a float

Comment: You need to show how you're calling `functioncall()`. Or possibly log the value of `f` and see how it could've gotten there.

Comment: @WhiteEyeTree Obviously it isn't, since it's an `int` or `float` as Python tells you.

Comment: @WhiteEyeTree: Post all of your code.

Comment: i call it using functioncall(f(<int here>),0.001). that f(<int>) return a float, what i'm asking is how can i call that function with a different argument while inside the functioncall function

Comment: if you do it like that, `f(...)` will get replaced by the return value of `f`, which is, as you described, float.

Comment: You are probably swapping arguments, also what is "that error"? Python generates some nice tracebacks, why don't you write them down?
Edit: just call it like `functioncall(f, 0.001)`.

Comment: @WhiteEyeTree just use `functioncall(f,0.001)`.

Answer (score 4):

You are actually passing the return value of the function `f` instead of the function object itself.

use just  : `functioncall(f,0.001)` when calling `functioncall`

if you do something like `functioncall(f(<int here>),0.001)`, then it sends the value returned by `f(<int here>)` as the first argument and calling `(guess)` on it raised the Error.

Comment: yeah, i understand that i'm using the value returned instead of the function, but i'm asking how could i call the function f with a different syntax, while keeping the call as functioncall(f(a),0.001)

Comment: @WhiteEyeTree I don't think there's any other way of calling a function, function is called using `()`.

Comment: @WhiteEyeTree why did you used `f(guess)` inside the function if you understand that you're passing the returned value of `f`?

Comment: Because i figured that out after i coded the function, but yet i hoped in some kind of trick because it could be very handy.

Comment: @WhiteEyeTree you want to pass both the returned value and the function object then why not try to pass 3 arguments(change functionall() to accept 3 args), because what you're thinking is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

For your code as written to work, the first argument passed to `functioncall` must be a function or other callable object. You are passing an int or float.